# Merge between two branches efficiently

Tags: git

I have two branches in a git repository named "up-to-date" and "work".
Regularly, I merge work to up-to-date. But in some cases I need to apply the latest commits of up-to-date to work.

I usually do in this case:

- select branch "up-to-date"
- merge "work" branch to "up-to-date"

and then otherwise:

- select branch "work"
- merge "up-to-date" to "work" branch

But there must be better solution to do this. What is the most efficient way to manage this?

Comment: It might be helpful to give some context, as described that workflow doesn't make much sense and it sounds like your repo looks like https://twitter.com/henryhoffman/status/694184106440200192

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: if you want to merge both "work" and "up-to-date", first merge "work" into "up-to-date", then move "work" branch onto "up-to-date" (i.e. `git checkout up-to-date && git merge work && git branch -f work`)

Explanation: usually when you want to merge your work branch into the trunk (i.e. what you are calling "up-to-date" and what is called "master" by default in git), it means that you have finished working on a particular feature or its part and are going to start working on a next one, so deleting and creating a "work" branch generally makes sense. In that context, such "work" branch is generally called somehow related to a feature being implemented in that branch, and it gets deleted once successfully merged into trunk (and a brand new branch gets created once the work on another feature starts).

Answer (score 0):

How about rebase "work" to "up-to-date"?

```
git checkout work
git rebase up-to-date
```

Answer (score -1):

Like mentioned before by CQLI, rebasing is a nice way to "update" your branch:

```
git checkout work
git rebase up-to-date
```

But keep in mind that a rebase will change history of your work branch.
So you need to be careful if other developers interacting with this branch.